# RLua 'hello world'-esque code not functioning without explanation

Tags: lua, roblox

New RLua programmer here - as far as I know, this syntax is correct (I'm trying to create a script that changes the colour of the baseplate, waits three seconds, and then loops infinitely. The code executes fine, with no syntax errors reported in the console.) Although for whatever reason, the baseplate will change colour once, and then stops completely. I'm sure if I put a little time in, I could root out the problem, but I'd rather receive advice from users more experienced in RLua than me and hopefully learn from it. Any help?

```
basenumber = 80
width = 20
height = 10
function base()
    Workspace.Baseplate.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Light reddish violet")
end
function base2()
    Workspace.Baseplate.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Baby blue")
end

local volume = 5
repeat print(volume)
    wait(1/16)
    volume = volume -1
    
until
volume == -1




if volume == -1 then
    repeat
        base()
        wait(3)
        base2()
        
    until basenumber == 10
end
```

Comment: You initialize `basenumber` with a value of `80`, and you use this variable in the repeat-until loop at the end of your script; but no where are you decrementing the value of `basenumber` so that it reaches the target of `10`. Also—and this is an issue subject to personal preference—I would recommend, for the sake of readability, rewriting your loops as while-loops.

Comment: @Personage `repeat .. until` and `while` loops are not always interchangeable. a `repeat ... until` loop body will always execute at least once, the body of a `while` loop on the other hand can execute 0 times.